# How to get current culture in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to know the current culture using SQL query?
To be more specific, Is there any SQL system function which will return me the Current Country name

Comment: If you stored that information inside the database then sure.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean current locale or collation?

Comment: Please tag with the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I am seeking a similar question - what is the culture for a connection/login as seen by SQL Server when the user is connected.  Perhaps this is what @Tahir is asking for. The only answer to this question as of now is how to get the language, but culture is used to format dates and numbers, so it is more than language.  Still seeking how...

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server:

To get the current session's language setting, and viewing the settings that are implicitly set by language:

```
select @@language;

select * 
from syslanguages 
where name = @@language;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WVB84402